# Html5 canvas line draw transition

Tags: html, animation, canvas, polyline, smoothing

Here I have canvas that draw line on canvas... every 300ms draw a line but its too hard for eyes...

LINK DEMO: http://jsbin.com/fabalo

CODE:

```
var test = [{"X":300,"Y":200}];
var set_time;
var m = 0;
var add_array = function(){
  ctx.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
    if(m < pts.length){
       var q = pts[m].X;
       var e = pts[m].Y;
       console.log(test);
       test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
       mimicSvg(test,1);

       m++;
       set_time = setTimeout(add_array,300);//it call itself again and again until m is more than the length of the array'
    }else{
       clearTimeout(set_time);
    }
};

set_time = setTimeout(add_array,300);
```

Is there any way that I can make animation transition to work smoothly?
What is the way to make this animation better? How to make transition?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in canvas. You'll have to find a way to make the easing/transition/tween function yourself.

First, you need to decide on a shorter interval and figure out how many "in-between" steps will be there and then use those for the transition.

Think about it as making a temporal x-step array between each two steps of your main array.

Comment: While "tweening" is generally useful in making an animation less jittery, in this case I can't see a way to apply your answer because each additional line segment causes a radical (non-incremental) repositioning in all the previous segments. One thought: Instead of snapping a new line segment in all at once, how about interpolating that segment and incrementally "growing" the segment into place. Perhaps that transition would be less jarring. I'm too tired tonight to give it a go--maybe you could give it a try?

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing - interpolation between point A to point B in X-number of steps.